# Create new column having summation of diff and Principal if Date is max(date)

Tags: r

Data:

```
  ID           Par      Date      Principal  summ    diff  summ.new
007036JH0    7707896 2020-03-25   135626.12 7707896 -0.01 135626.12
007036JH0    7707896 2020-04-27   153919.34 7707896 -0.01 153919.34
007036JH0    7707896 2020-05-26   189843.35 7707896 -0.01 189843.35
007036JH0    7707896 2020-06-25   184767.42 7707896 -0.01 184767.42
007036JH0    7707896 2020-07-27   187981.41 7707896 -0.01 187981.41
007036JH0    7707896 2020-08-25   188668.81 7707896 -0.01 188668.81
007036JH0    7707896 2020-09-25   185205.98 7707896 -0.01 185205.98
007036JH0    7707896 2020-10-26   167851.27 7707896 -0.01 167851.27
```

Query:

Using the mentioned code and dataframe, I am trying to add diff to Principal if the Date is max(date) else just assign Principal to the new column summ.new.

Note: This is sample data so it has only one ID. I have several ID therefore i am  using for loop. 
Let me know if more info required.

Code:

```
for(i in vec){   
  if(df5$Post.Date[j]==max(df5$Post.Date)){     
     df5$summ.new <- df5$Principal.x + abs(df5$diff)
  } else {
     df5$summ.new <- df5$Principal.x    
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add `diff` value if Date is `max` `Date` for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(summ.new = ifelse(Date == max(Date), Principal + abs(diff), Principal))
```

The same logic in `data.table` can be written as :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, summ.new := ifelse(Date == max(Date), Principal + abs(diff), Principal), ID]
```

---

Although using `ifelse` is easy to understand but this can be done without it as well.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(summ.new = Principal + (abs(diff) * (Date == max(Date))))
```

and

```
setDT(df)[, summ.new := Principal + (abs(diff) * (Date == max(Date))), ID]
```

Comment: First one using dplyr worked perfectly. Thanks Ronak.I am curious to know the error in my code using for loop. Some more info: vec is a vector created of unique ID's in dataframe and j is length of the dataframe. Thanks

Comment: There are lot of issues actually. Some of them are 1) In both `if` and `else` when you are doing `df5$summ.new <- `, you are changing the entire column of dataframe and not only the max one. 2) `df5$Post.Date[j]==max(df5$Post.Date)` is only checking for last row in `df5` with `max` value of entire dataframe. 3) it is not considering group column i.e `ID` column at all. `for` loop is not the best option for such grouped operation, there are functions designed specially to deal with them.